# The input field is not updating "address" in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

I am creating a table which is looping through an array and displays the array in the table as list. I am displaying the address as an input field value `:value="location.address"`

The input fields are set to disabled and when I click on the edit button I updated the disabled property to false so that the input field can be edited. I have added a new property called `editedAddress: null` and set that to null which is updated to the current address property `this.editedAddress = this.locations[index].address`.

What I want is that when I click on the edit button, I want the address to be updated. I have added the following code for the update button but it does not work.

```
btnUpdate(index){
       this.locations[index].address = this.editedAddress;
        this.locations[index].disabled = !this.locations[index].disabled
    }
```

Here is the full code

```
<template>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Locations</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="(location, index) in locations" :key="index">
        <td>{{index + 1}}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" :value="location.address" :disabled="location.disabled">
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="action-btns">
            <button @click="btnEdit(index)">Edit</button>
            <button @click="btnUpdate(index)">Update</button>
            <button @click="btnDelete(index)">Delete</button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="text" v-model="address"> 
    <button @click="addBtn">Add</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data(){
    return{
      locations:[
        {
          address:'Mall of lahore',
          disabled: true
        },
        {
          address: 'The Post Office',
          disabled: true
        },
        {
          address: 'Mall of Dubai',
          disabled: true
        }
      ],
      address: '',
      editedAddress: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    btnEdit(index){
     this.locations[index].disabled = !this.locations[index].disabled
     this.editedAddress = this.locations[index].address
    },
    btnUpdate(index){
       this.locations[index].address = this.editedAddress;
        this.locations[index].disabled = !this.locations[index].disabled
    },
    btnDelete(index){
      this.locations.splice(index , 1)
    },
    addBtn(){
      let newAddress = {
        address: this.address,
        disabled: true
      }
      this.locations.push(newAddress)
      this.address = '';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or if there is a better way to solve it

Comment: can you explain it clearly? what's the behavior you want after clicking the edit button? set the input value to null?

Comment: When I click on the edit button, 1.) I want the input field disabled attribute to be false, so that I can edit it. This part I have done. 2.) When I update the input field, clicking on the update button should update the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input field is bound to `location.address`.
So, you are not editing your `editedAddress` at all.

You can add `@change="editedAddress = $event.target.value"` to your input field to change `editedAddress`

```
 <input type="text" :value="location.address" :disabled="location.disabled" @change="editedAddress = $event.target.value" >
```

Tip: use [Vue Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg) or JSON.stringify to check the data in your vue app

```
JSON.stringify(editedAddress): {{JSON.stringify(editedAddress)}}
```

Here is the [link playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with the fix

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Can you clarify index: -1 which you added in the data() and setting this.index = index; in btnEdit and btnUpdate functions?

Thanks again

Comment: You don't need to store the index. I have added it to check what's going on and forgot to delete it. :-)

Comment: I was not sure, if the index in the btnUpdate() method was right and added a display item `{{index}}` to check it.

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't explain what exactly do you mean by "I have added the following code for the update button but it does not work" I will assume that you UI is not being updated.

This is a caveats of reactivity in Vue reactive system https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

Probably Vue is not being able to pick that there were a change in your item inside the array `locations`.

To make Vue understand that there was a change you can use `Vue.set`:

```
btnUpdate(index){
  Vue.set(this.locations[index], 'address', this.editedAddress);
  // do the same for the other line
},
```

After this Vue should be able to pick that there was a change and re-render the UI for you.

Another approach is to replace the entire array (but in most cases this is a bit overkill)

```
btnUpdate(index){
  const locations = [...this.locations];
  
  locations[index].address = this.editedAddress;

  this.locations = locations;
},
```

Comment: @Tolbxela a little bit more elaboration would be nice

Comment: I just needed time to write the answer. :-)

Comment: Sorry @null, but your answer has nothing to do with the problem in the question code. :-) . The problem is with binding, not reactivity. Re-check the Vue Docs: Form Input Bindings. https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html